# I can't practice data scraping using javascript

Tags: javascript, web, screen-scraping

I was trying to practice data scraping for our project and I can successfully see the data if I enter node scrapers.js. However, when I load it into a livecount.html file, there's an error showing and I can't display the data collected from data scraping.

The error is:
"was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)"

Here's the code from the html file

> ```
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
> </head>
> <body>
>     Total cases: 
>     <span id="totalCases"></span> <br>
>     Recovered cases:
>     <span id="recovered"></span> <br>
>     <script src="scrapers.js" type="text/html">
>     </script>
> </body> </html>
> ```

and here's the code from scrapers.js

> const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
>
> ```
>     async function scrapeProduct(url){
>         const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
>         const page = await browser.newPage();
>         await page.goto(url);
>     
>         const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]');
>         const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
>         const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();
>     
>         console.log(rawTxt);
>         
>         const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]');
>         const txt2 = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
>         const recovered = await txt2.jsonValue(); 
>         
>         console.log(recovered);
>         browser.close();
>         document.write("total cases: " + rawTxt + "\n" + "recovered: " + recovered);
>     }
>     
>     scrapeProduct('https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=en-PH&gl=PH&ceid=PH%3Aen&mid=%2Fm%2F05v8c');
> ```

I'm just new to these things so I don't really know how things works, just practicing stuff for our website project, and I wanted to display data to our website from another website. Any opinions will help! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Scraping is usually done on the server, not on the browser. I recommend changing your project structure as below.

[As-is] html > js > puppeteer > ?  
[To-be] html > js > ajax call to your server[nodejs] -> get data from server :)